# Implement methodMissing() for closure delegate

Tags: java, groovy, closures

I'm trying to implement a somewhat general DSL with Java and Groovy. The idea is to have a syntax like `data { name 'my name' }` and to intercept all the method calls with `methodMissing` where I can check that the method name equals to a field and set it up by running the closure. I use Java to write my data class and it looks like this.

```
public class TestData {
    @Getter @Setter
    protected String name;

    public void call(Closure closure) {
        closure.setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST);
        closure.setDelegate(this);
        closure.call();
    }

    public Object methodMissing(String name, Object args) {
        // here we extract the closure from arguments, etc
       return "methodMissing called with name '" + name + "' and args = " + argsList;
    }
}
```

The code to run a DSL script is this

```
    TestData testData = new TestData();
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
    binding.setVariable("data", testData);
    Object result = shell.evaluate("data { name 'my test data' }");
```

The problem is, `closure.call()` returns a `MissingMethodException`:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.name() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [my test data]`
How can I make it redirect the method calls to its delegate  and to look for its `methodMissing` method?

Comment: Instead of using evaluate, you can use the parse method which returns a Script Object and then call setDelegate on that before invoking its run method.

Comment: Thank you. This helps, but now `methodMissing` is always called for the `TestData` instance I set as the script's delegate. `closure.setDelegate(value); closure.run()` doesn't call the `value`'s `methodMissing()`

Comment: I've found the solution: `TestData` should extend `GroovyObjectSupport` which contains a `MetaClass` which, in turn, redirects all missing method calls to the `methodMissing` of the right object.

Comment: @AndrewSokolov Why not write your own solution and accept it as answer.